# CORS problem to call WFS layer using OL-Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, wfs, tomcat, cors

The problem I have is with the well known CORS configuration that there is already so much documentation to solve it but I am not really succeeding. I am working in Ubuntu v.22

I am working on a virtual computer or "environment". Within the latter, I have already modified in the web.xml file of Geoserver (path: (webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/web.xml)) the TOMCAT section, which is the server in which I work, related to the CORS header. I have also done the same for the JSONP and FILTERMAPPING sections. I attach thes parts I've mentioned about this.

1-[image]

2-`<!-- Uncomment following filter to enable CORS in Tomcat. Do not forget the second config block further down.--> <filter> <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name> <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class> <init-param> <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name> <param-value>*</param-value> </init-param> <init-param> <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name> <param-value>GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,HEAD,OPTIONS</param-value> </init-param> <init-param> <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name> <param-value>*</param-value> </init-param> </filter>`

3- `<!-- Uncomment following filter-mapping to enable CORS --> <filter-mapping> <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name> <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> </filter-mapping>`

My html. and js. code work correctly, they do not have any errors and I can display normally a series of base maps, but not so with this WFS layer that I want to load that is in GEOSERVER.

I add, in case it is useful, that I have had the same problem when I tried to use the Leaflet library.

This is the error:
Cross-origin request blocked: The same-origin policy does not allow reading the remote resource at http://............/geoserver/....../ows?&. (Reason: missing CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'). Status code: 200

Has anyone had the same problem?

Comment: please don't post pictures of text, it is very hard or impossible for some readers. Please also add the **exact** error message you are getting for which request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of effort on this CORS issue, I found the solution.
There is another file that I have not read in the documentation that also works the CORS parameters. It is found, at least in my case, in the address: /var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/web.xml
I edited it with "nano" on my Ubuntu virtual server. That is, I uncommented the same sections as in the file I mention above.